# If $ST$ is a nilpotent operator then so is $TS$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $T, S \in L(V)$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space. I am trying to prove that if $ST$ is nilpotent, then $TS$ is nilpotent.

First I consider the case $ST=0$.  From here, I want to show that $TS=0$. Suppose on the contrary that it is not so. There exists a non zero $v\in \rm range \,TS$ and a $u$ such that $v=TSu$.

$Sv=STSu=0\implies Sv=0\implies 0$ is an eigenvalue of $S$ and $v\in \rm null \, S$.

I don't know how to proceed from here. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: If $(ST)^n=0$ (zero matrix), what does $(TS)^k$ look like (write it in expanded form)? Can the factors be regrouped in a helpful way?  Can you find a value of $k$ that makes this zero?

Comment: It's not true that $ST=0$ implies $TS=0$ by the way. However, $(TS)^2=TSTS$ is indeed $0$, as it is a multiple of $ST$.

Comment: @DavidP: yes, that makes sense by using the fact that null $(ST)^n$=null $(ST)^{n+1}$,where n = dim V. I also thought of using the following fact: There is a basis of V w.r.t. which ST will have an upper triangular matrix with 0 on its diagonal entries. But that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. I was trying to prove the wrong statement.